# How to properly use regex to search from a command's output in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, conditional-statements

I have a command `lando info` which has a fairly large multi-line output:

```
[ { service: 'appserver',
    urls:
     [ 'https://localhost:52836',
       'http://localhost:52837',
       'http://if-build-d9.lndo.site/',
       'https://if-build-d9.lndo.site/' ],
    type: 'php',
    healthy: true,
    via: 'apache',
    webroot: './web',
    config: { php: '/Users/runo/.lando/config/drupal9/php.ini' },
    version: '7.3',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hasCerts: true,
    hostnames: [ 'appserver.ifbuildd9.internal' ] },
  { service: 'database',
    urls: [],
    type: 'mysql',
    healthy: true,
    internal_connection: { host: 'database', port: '3306' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: '52835' },
    healthcheck: 'bash -c "[ -f /bitnami/mysql/.mysql_initialized ]"',
    creds: { database: 'drupal9', password: 'drupal9', user: 'drupal9' },
    config: { database: '/Users/runo/.lando/config/drupal9/mysql.cnf' },
    version: '5.7',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hasCerts: false,
    hostnames: [ 'database.ifbuildd9.internal' ] },
  { service: 'redis_primary',
    urls: [ 'http://if-build-d9-redis-primary.lndo.site/' ],
    type: 'redis',
    healthy: true,
    internal_connection: { host: 'redis_primary', port: '6379' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: '52838' },
    config: {},
    version: '6',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hasCerts: false,
    hostnames: [ 'redis_primary.ifbuildd9.internal' ] },
  { service: 'mailhog',
    urls: [ 'http://localhost:52840', 'http://if-build-d9-mail.lndo.site/' ],
    type: 'mailhog',
    healthy: true,
    hogfrom: [ 'appserver' ],
    internal_connection: { host: 'mailhog', port: '1025' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: '52839' },
    config: {},
    version: 'v1.0.0',
    meUser: 'mailhog',
    hasCerts: false,
    hostnames: [ 'mailhog.ifbuildd9.internal' ] } ]
```

I want to capture the value `http://if-build-d9.lndo.site` in a bash variable.

What I have is this shell script, but it returns empty values:

```
 lando_info=$(lando info); 
 regex_pattern='/http:\/\/[\w\S]*.lndo.site/g'; 
 [[ "$lando_info" =~ $regex_pattern ]]; 
 echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
 echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
 echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

**This outputs empty strings.**

I know the regex itself should be valid as I tested it on https://www.regexpal.com/ with that command output and pattern.

It matches on

- `http://if-build-d9.lndo.site` (this is the only match I care about)
- `http://if-build-d9-redis-primary.lndo.site`
- `http://if-build-d9-mail.lndo.site`

So it appears that my use of regex in Bash is not correct.

Comment: Replace `[\w\S]` with `\S` and do not use regex delimiters/flags. The pattern should be a plain string, something like `regex_pattern='http://\S*\.lndo\.site'`

Comment: You can only get the first match in Bash. Check https://ideone.com/CubY6K

Comment: Maybe you just want `grep -oE 'http://[^[:space:]]*\.lndo\.site' <<< "$lando_info"`? See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/2mog4R).

Comment: /So... you want **1** extract the values from path `"service" == "appserver" --> "urls"`.  **2** From these values, remove the ones with `localhost` and `https` lines.  What format is that output?  It looks close to JSON, but does not validate.  You might be able to use `jq` if it is not too out of spec.  Using `grep` implies that urls with the wanted pattern are not found anywhere else in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) with better results.

Answer (score 1):

Bash uses POSIX ERE regex flavor, `[\w\S]` matches a `\`, `w` or `S` and not any char but whitespace as you expected.

It looks like you just want to `grep -o`ut the URLs with a specific pattern, so use

```sh
grep -oE 'http://[^[:space:]]*\.lndo\.site' <<< "$lando_info"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2mog4R). Output:

```
http://if-build-d9.lndo.site
http://if-build-d9-redis-primary.lndo.site
http://if-build-d9-mail.lndo.site
```

The `[^[:space:]]*` is a negated bracket expression that contains a POSIX character class and matches any zero or more chars other than whitespace chars. `-o` option allows `grep` to extract matches only, not matched lines.